# why are more destroyed objects than created

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

am new to c++ and and trying to learn the cost of copying values or passing references, in my example I found though a segment of code that is for me hard to understand:

consider this example:

```
struct Foo {

    Foo(int x) :
            internVal { x } {
        std::cout << "Con: " << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "Des: " << std::endl;
    }
    int getVal() const {
        return internVal;
}
private:
    int internVal { 0 };
};
```

now when I do:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    {
        Foo a { 111 };
        Foo b { 6555 };
        Foo c { -444 };
        std::cout << " Foos created..." << std::endl;
        std::vector<Foo> vector_Test { };
        vector_Test.push_back(a);
        vector_Test.push_back(b);
        vector_Test.push_back(c);
        std::cout << " Foos added..." << std::endl;

        for (const auto& d : vector_Test) {
            std::cout << "-----" << d.getVal() << "-----" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << " Foos printed..." << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << " Foos out of scope..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "end!" << std::endl;

    //
    return 0;
}
```

I see the following output:

```
Con: 
Con: 
Con: 
 Foos created...
Des: 
Des: 
Des: 
 Foos added...
-----111-----
-----6555-----
------444-----
 Foos printed...
Des: 
Des: 
Des: 
Des: 
Des: 
Des: 
 Foos out of scope...
end!
```

so my question  why are more objects destroyed as created?

I would expect an even number... if I create directly/ indirectly 3 objects then destroy 3 objects

Do I habe a memory leak some where?

thanks

Ps: my compiler is MinWG

Comment: Because you don't instrument all the possible constructors.

Comment: There is an implicit copy constructor that you haven't accounted for.

Comment: oh...  that is a good one... copy constructor for sure is missing

Comment: Add copy constructor and log it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `vector_Test.push_back(a);` you are adding a copy of the instance to the vector.

Which means later on those copies and the original elements get destroyed.